# Finding holomorphic functions satisfying certain conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

Determine all the holomorphic functions $f$ from the open unit disk $D=\{z:|z|<1\}$ to whole complex plane which satisfies $f''(\frac{1}{n})+f(\frac{1}{n})=0$ for all $n=2,3,4,\ldots$

At first when i saw the differential equation, all i thought is the sine and cosine function, but the trouble is i dont know how should i use the given unit disk and the "$\frac{1}{n}$" in the parentheses.

Anyone can guide me or give some hints for me?

Comment: Hint: propose a function intuitively and use the identity principle

Comment: In conventional mathematical terminology, one says either $\text{“for all } n\in\{2,3,4,\ldots\}\text{''}$ or $\text{“for } n=2,3,4,\ldots\text{''}$ $($this second form without the word $\text{“all''}).$ $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people are mentioning the "identity theorem", which is reported in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) to say that if two holomorphic functions defined on some open subset $D$ of the plane agree with each other on some non-empty open subset of $D$, then the agree on $D$.  But here what you're given is not agreement on some non-empty open subset of $D$, but satisfaction of a differential equation on a convergent sequence of points in $D$.

You know $f$ is holomorphic in $D$; hence according to the proof given in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyticity_of_holomorphic_functions), we have
$$
f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} z^n \tag 1
$$
for all $z$ in $D$ (generally for all $z$ closer to $0$ than the nearest point to which $f$ cannot be analytically continued, and there are no such ill-behaved points within the disk $D$).

Power series can be differentiated term by term within the interior of their disk of convergence.  So if you know $(1)$ and if you can show that $f''(0)+f(0)=0$, then all of the coefficients of the power series will be determined by $f(0)$ and $f'(0)$.  And then you have a series that you know converges to $f(0)\cos z + f'(0)\sin z$.

So how do you show that if $f''+f=0$ at $1/n$ for $n=2,3,4,\ldots$ then $f''+f=0$ at $0$?  Here I'd think about the smooth nature of functions defined by convergent power series.

Comment: Many (most?) complex analysis books state the identity theorem as the more general statement, that if holomorphic $f$ is 0 on a set with a limit point, then $f=0$.

Comment: @MikeMiller : So the Wikipedia article could use some work.  Maybe I'll look at it and cite something in Ahlfors or some other suitable text unless someone beats me to it. $\qquad$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hint: let $g = f'' + f$. What then do you know about $g$? (Think identity theorem.)